# Turn text or link field in image

Tags: 7, entities, navigation

Users can enter links in separate fields that lead to their facebook, youtube pages.

On output i would like to use images for those fields instead of showing ugly links.

Is there a module to acomplish this ?

Comment: I am not sure if there is a module for that. If it is a menu link there is https://drupal.org/project/menu_icons to handle that. However, for this kind of work I would use CSS to replace text with images. It is pretty simple and fast.

Comment: are the urls displaying as plain text or links?

Comment: Don't know if you want icons or text converted to image? For the latter you can use https://www.drupal.org/project/textimage

Comment: Links to images, which lead to face, yt, etc. when clicked.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to implement this is to implement a custom display formatter for the link field. You can either do it directly in a custom module by implementing `hook_field_formatter_info`.

Or without try out [Custom Formatters](https://www.drupal.org/project/custom_formatters) module if you want to avoid custom code:

> The Custom Formatters module allows users to easily create custom Field Formatters without the need to write a custom module. Custom Formatters can then be exported as CTools Exportables, Features or Drupal API Field Formatters.

Answer (score 0):

Try this modules

1. [Image Link Formatter](https://www.drupal.org/project/image_link_formatter)
2. [Link Image Field](https://www.drupal.org/project/linkimagefield)

Answer (score 0):

You can also do the same using CSS. Just set color of link as white, and place background-image for the anchor tag, and set text-indent.